# Error in SQL syntax at line 1

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to create an examination using MySQL in Java where repetition of number is not allowed.

I'm having a hard time locating my error. I've been debugging my code for hours now.

> Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'null WHERE number = 1' at line 1

Below is my code

```
    String examNames = examName.getName();
    String searchNumber = "SELECT * FROM " + examNames + " WHERE number = ?";
    PreparedStatement preparedNumber = connect.prepareStatement(searchNumber);
    int examNumbers = Integer.parseInt(textNumber.getText());
    preparedNumber.setInt(1, examNumbers);
    ResultSet results = preparedNumber.executeQuery();
    if (results.next()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exam number was already added");
    }

    else {
        String examLabel = examName.getText();
        String insertContent = " Insert INTO " + examLabel
                + "(number, content, choiceA, choiceB, choiceC, choiceD, correctans) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,'"
                + correctAns + "')";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(insertContent);
        int examNumber = Integer.parseInt(textNumber.getText());
        String content = textAreaQuestion.getText();
        String choiceA = textAreaA.getText();
        String choiceB = textAreaB.getText();
        String choiceC = textAreaC.getText();
        String choiceD = textAreaD.getText();
        String correct = correctAns;
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, examNumber);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, content);
        preparedStatement.setString(3, choiceA);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, choiceB);
        preparedStatement.setString(5, choiceC);
        preparedStatement.setString(6, choiceD);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Added");
    }
```

Comment: becuase examNames is null

Comment: does it mean that .getText() can't get the Jlabel value? I also tried using .getName() but still null. I tried replacing it with a text field and it works. but I need to use Jlabel

Comment: Might be an idea to include the code where examName was created... Which should include a setText if you expect getText to return anything.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt responses. It works now. The error was in my other class :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it says

`'null WHERE number = 1'`

then it means that

`String examNames= examName.getName();`

is returning null

Answer (score 0):

In class 1 create a method that returns the text of NewLabel (you can do this by putting the NewLabel's text in a String object,say str,and then return str).

Now in class 2 ,create an object of class 1,(e.g. Class1 cl1=new Class1();).Now simply call that method you created in class 1(e.g.,cl1.getNewLabelText()) .getNewLabelText() is a sample name you can give to your method created for class